# Despite method as post, In link_to the params get added to URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The problem with submission of data in my form through GET is that the url length gets exceeded. So I switched to post.

Instead of using gems like will_paginate which I would tried and failed to use via POST call, I am doing something like this.

```
<%= link_to "Next", {:controller => "orders", :action => "advanced_search", :method => :post, :page => params[:page].to_i+1, :filters => params[:filters], :limit => params[:limit]}%>
```

The problem is that despite the method being post, it still merges params to the url itself. I basically want it to submit the form again, with the new page parameter. But without the params populating the url.

I would really be glad, if anyone could help me out with this.

UPDATE: The url looks like

```
http://localhost:3000/orders/advanced_search?filters%5Bapproved_between%5D=&filters%5Bcreated_between%5D=&filters%5Border_id%5D=0111T20822130100%0D%0AO11221D208211501118%0D%0AO11D208211501118%0D%0AO11T20822130100%0D%0AO121D208211501118%0D%0AO1221D208211501118%0D%0AO1D208211501118%0D%0AO1T20822140003&filters%5Bproduct_id%5D=&filters%5Bshipped_between%5D=&filters%5Bsku%5D=&method=post&limit=50&page=2
```

I trimmed the url from the center. The browser throws up the error - Request-URI Too Large

UPDATE 2: I am now using this which is NOT WORKING. (I was presumptuous that it would work before properly testing).

```
<%= form_tag :controller=> "orders", :action => "advanced_search", :new_params => params.merge(:page => params[:page].to_i+1) do %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Next' %>
   <% end %>
```

While this sends the new_params, it still changes the URL despite the form method being POST. It wraps the data in the form action link as orders/advanced_search?new_params.............. URGH!!!!

Comment: What do the URLs look like?

Comment: @jason328 - Just update the question. Look towards the start/end of url for the other params.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `:method => :post` to a link does not make it a post request. It simply adds a GET variable named `method`.

`link_to` will not create POST links. `link_to` creates `<a>` elements, and unless you're using JavaScript in there, the browser will execute a `GET` request.

In order to use a `POST` request, you will have to use a form.

I would try to see if there's another way than to pass all those variables. It's always nice to be able to paste/bookmark the link to a page.

**Edit:**

Try something like this

```
<%= form_for :orders, :url => order_advanced_search_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden :filters, params[:filters] %>
  <%= form.hidden :page, params[:page].to_i + 1 %>
  <%= form.hidden :limit, params[:limit] %>
  <%= form.submit "Next" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thought that :(....It's very similar with the button_to. I just want to update my page param, and call the controller when the user clicks next. What would you do to make that happen?

Comment: If there's no way to pass less variables, then use a form.

Comment: It's not me...But there you go for trying. I made it back to 0. I have updated my question, can you help?